# como fazer o tempo aparecer na janela(label)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tenho o seguinte código de um "temporizador", porém ele não aparece na janela, só no console do Python 3.6. Como fazer para ele ser impresso na janela? (obs.: a janela só abre quando acaba o tempo pré-definido)

```
from tkinter import*
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep
janela = Tk()

segundos = int("3")#tempo que comeca 
tempo = timedelta(seconds=segundos)

while (str(tempo) >= "00:00:00"):
    stdout.write("\r%s" % tempo)
    tempo = tempo - timedelta(seconds=1)
    sleep(1)




janela.title("tempo")
janela["bg"] = "white"
janela.geometry("500x500")
janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Se a janela só abre depois que acaba o tempo, como quer mostrar o tempo na janela?

Comment: Isso que eu quero saber como fazer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa criar um label em sua janela, apos isto é preciso renderizar e definir a lógica de atualização do label onde o tempo será exibido.

utilizando seu código, fiz algumas adaptações, veja se funciona:

```
import time
from tkinter import*
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sys import stdout

segundos = 3

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.janela = Tk()
        self.janela.title("tempo")
        self.janela.geometry("500x500")

        self.label = Label()
        self.tempo = timedelta(seconds=segundos)
        self.atualizarTemporizador()

        self.label.pack()
        self.janela.mainloop()

    def atualizarTemporizador(self):
        self.label.configure(text=self.tempo)
        if self.tempo > timedelta(seconds=0):
            self.tempo = self.tempo - timedelta(seconds=1)
            self.janela.after(1000, self.atualizarTemporizador)
            stdout.write("\r%s" % self.tempo)

app = App()
```

Answer (score 0):

Minha resposta é parecida com a do @brow-joe, mas como eu testei a dele e deu um erro, resolvi colocar a minha também (ambiente: Python 3.6):

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class showtime():
    def __init__(self, t=30):
        self.ticker=t
        self.count = 0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(text="00:00:00")
        self.label.pack()
        self.update_label()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_label (self):
        if self.count>=self.ticker:
            self.root.destroy()
            return
        else:
            self.count+=1
            now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            self.label.configure(text=now)
            self.root.after(1000, self.update_label)

app = showtime(10)        
print ('script terminado')
```

Comment: eita kk, qual erro deu? também estou utilizando o `Python 3.6.0`

Comment: achei kk, mudei o nome da classe e esqueci de mudar em baixo, editei a resposta com o codigo corrigido, obrigado